# Dynamic type format of DateTime, c#

Tags: asp.net-mvc, datetime-format

I have a json structure below, whose format changes with each request, and am sending this as a POST payload into .Net MVC 4.

```
{"id":40388111,"parameters":[{"fid":40388138,"all":true,"isaccounts":true},{"fid":40388139,"value":"2014-10-02T00:00:00.000Z"}],"output":"json","start":0,"limit":25}
```

The controller action looks like:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Execute(dynamic payload)
{
    string postData = Convert.ToString(payload);
    var vm = await _service.Execute(postData);
    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, vm, new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json"));
}
```

The problem is the string postData becomes:

```
{
  "id": 40388111,
  "parameters": [
    {
      "fid": 40388138,
      "all": true,
      "isaccounts": true
    },
    {
      "fid": 40388139,
      "value": "2014-10-02T00:00:00Z"
    }
  ],
  "output": "json",
  "start": 0,
  "limit": 25
}
```

And what you will notice is the milliseconds is missing from the date, which is causing issues within the service receiving this postData string.  How do I get the postData string date to be the same as the incoming payload date format?

Comment: If you use the debugger, what's the *actual* type of `payload`?

Comment: The date in the dynamic is 2014-10-02T00:00Z

Comment: That's not what I asked at all though... `dynamic` isn't a type in the CLR's type system; it's just a way of telling C# to bind dynamically. So the object that `payload` refers to at execution time has a type... what is that type?

Comment: Hopefully this will answer your question Jon.  The json is created in javascript, and added to an AJAX POST request as the payload, and the date is send along as a string as "2014-10-02T00:00:00.000Z".  I have not created a type in C# to represent the payload as it is generated dynamically in Javascript and changes.  This json string is sent along directly to another service.  I guess what I really need is a way to get a json structure from a POST payload as a string without modification by the MVC framework.

Comment: Nope, that doesn't answer it. If you call `payload.GetType()`, what does it return?

Comment: IsValueType: false
    IsVisible: true
    MemberType: TypeInfo
    Module: {Newtonsoft.Json.dll}
    Namespace: "Newtonsoft.Json.Linq"
    ReflectedType: null
    StructLayoutAttribute: {System.Runtime.InteropServices.StructLayoutAttribute}
    TypeHandle: {System.RuntimeTypeHandle}
    TypeInitializer: null
    UnderlyingSystemType: {Name = "JObject" FullName = "Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject"}

Comment: Okay, so the answer is `JObject`... so you should probably be checking the Json.NET documentation about date/time formats. If you just want the payload as a string, have you tried changing the parameter type to just `string`? Currently you're parsing it and then reformatting it...

Comment: (Alternatively, change your service to accept the parsed JSON in some form, so it doesn't do the string conversion itself.)